# Change the background picture in Android

Tags: android, background-image

I want to change the picture of the background in my app in Android Studio depending on a few conditions. This is my code:

```
switch (sky_state) {
    case "SUNNY":
        // Here I want to change the background
        break;
}
```

I know how to change it in the XML file of the layout, but is it possible to access this property from the code outside the layout file?

Comment: ImageView imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that...
Use the following line of code for that particular view...

```
        switch (sky_state) {
        case "SUNNY":
            view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_send));
            break;
        }
```

Let me know if this works for you and mark as an answer if it does, so that it would be useful to others.....

Comment: Yes, it works but finally I find setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image)

Answer (score 1):

view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icsend));

Comment: Add some description to it.